# Local Notification repeats indefinitely- Swift

Tags: ios, swift, localnotification

I scheduled a local notification that should be activated after several hours without the user using the app. The problem I am having is that once it fires, the notification is repeated constantly until the app goes on the foreground. I would like for it to appear once only.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

        localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: (86400)*3)
        localNotification.alertTitle = "Te Extrañamos"
        localNotification.alertBody = "No olvides tu estudio en Momentos de Tora"
        localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)     
    }

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(localNotification)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can somebody explain why I'm getting negative points from this question, so that I can avoid it in the future? :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is keep track of you have sent the notification yet. Save a variable like `let sentNotification: bool = false` in your method before you send the notification check this variable. Then inside that check set it to `true`. In the applicationDidEnterForground method set it to `false`. So it will fire again when the parameters are reached.